# Clarifications on salesforce 2g packages

Tags: managed-package, package, unlocked-package, unmanaged-package, 2gp

I am working on 2g package generation and these are few questions troubling me :

1. Is it mandatory to keep metadata in namespace org to create 2g package version. What if namespace org is empty and all metadata are available at git.
2. Where **SFDX version create** command verify metadata data? Namespace org or scratch org?
3. Once Package version creation is successful, Where does salesforce stores these packages ? Is it devHub or namespace org?
4. reached maximum number of custom objects limit while creating package version but metadata were successfully deployed in scratch org and deploy org. few questions here :-

- Why again objects limit are calculated?
- Against which org these objects limit are calculated?
- If answer is that Package also has its own object limits, how much objects can be added in a package?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it mandatory to keep metadata in namespace org to create 2g package version. What if namespace org is empty and all metadata are available at git.

The git repo is the Source of Truth. You do not need to keep any metadata at all in the namespace org. Only the metadata in the git repo will be in the package.

> Where SFDX version create command verify metadata data? Namespace org or scratch org?

It creates a temporary scratch org to perform the verification. This is not any scratch org you created, a Sandbox, Developer, or Production org, just a temporary, throw-away org that you will never log in to or use.

> Once Package version creation is successful, Where does salesforce stores these packages ? Is it devHub or namespace org?

The Dev Hub org hosts these packages (typically a Production or Developer Edition org). The namespace org is used only to reserve the namespace for your packages.

> - Why again objects limit are calculated?
> - Against which org these objects limit are calculated?
> - If answer is that Package also has its own object limits, how much objects can be added in a package?

The limits are calculated in a temporary scratch org, as above. The [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) controls these limits. If you specify a smaller org, such as a Group Edition org, you'll be severely limited on your limits (Group and Professional have a 50 custom object limit, Enterprise 200, Developer 400, Unlimited 2,000).

Keep in mind also, that if you create a package too large for an org type, you won't be able to install it, even if you create the version successfully.

You can also increase the limit in the Scratch Org Definition file by adding "AddCustomObjects:x" (where x is up to 30), but if the org you want to install to doesn't have enough space, the installation will fail.